# Minimizing WCF client footprint

Tags: wcf, web-config

Can somebody through some light on this?

How can I eliminate the need of updating web references and minimize the WCF client footprint in `web.config` in order to improved code maintainability.

Thanks in advance

BB

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely sure what you mean by *minimize WCF client footprint* - but the VS tools and `svcutil.exe` typically do way too much stuff - so doing things manually, *knowing* what you do, can definitely minimize the amount of code and config you need.

For that, there's are a bunch of video resources for WCF that deal with that exact topic:

- DotNet Rocks TV Show #122: [Miguel Castro on Extreme WCF](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=122)
- DotNet Rocks TV Show #135: [Keith Elder Demystifies WCF](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=135)

Answer (score 1):

The best bet is to do away with service references altogether. However you can only do this if you have access to the assemblies which contain the actual service interface, operation contracts, and data contracts. Then you can create a service proxy on the fly using ChannelFactory:

```
// Create service proxy
var factory = new ChannelFactory<IMyServiceContract>("NameOfEndPointInConfigFile");
var proxy = factory.CreateChannel();

// Call the operation
var myRequestDataContractType = new myRequestDataContractType();
var myResponseDataContractType = proxy.MyServiceOperation(myRequestDataContractType);
```

In your config file all you need is the endpoint definition:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <client>
    <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8000/MyService" 
              binding="netTcpBinding"
              contract="ServiceNamespace.IMyServiceContract"
              name="NameOfEndPointInConfigFile">
    </endpoint>
  </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Thats about as minimal as you can get.